# How this recursion function works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I was looking for a solution to the Minimum Sum Partition Problem, and I found this [Link](https://www.techiedelight.com/minimum-sum-partition-problem/).

I couldn't find out how recursion works in this function especially the base condition.

A more general question I have is for example for calculating `inc` the recursion continues till n will be `-1` then it will go to the base case, then `case 2`?

you can see the function body below.

```
// Partition the set S into two subsets S1, S2 such that the
// difference between the sum of elements in S1 and the sum
// of elements in S2 is minimized
int minPartition(int S[], int n, int S1, int S2)
{
    // base case: if list becomes empty, return the absolute
    // difference between two sets
    if (n < 0)
    {
        return abs(S1 - S2);

    }

    // Case 1. include current item in the subset S1 and recur
    // for remaining items (n - 1)
    int inc = minPartition(S, n - 1, S1 + S[n], S2);

    // Case 2. exclude current item from subset S1 and recur for
    // remaining items (n - 1)
    int exc = minPartition(S, n - 1, S1, S2 + S[n]);
    return min (inc, exc);

}
```

*I tried to introduce my question in a proper way that fits the standards but let me know If I can make it better and have a more positive effect on the community.*

Thank you very much for your time and help in advance.

Comment: What happens when you debug it? Add some `printf()` statements, where you use `n` (or some number minus `n`) as a an indentation (for visibly seeing the recursion depth), and you might understand how this all is working.

Comment: @Dominique I already tried but I couldn't understand much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: If you understand c++ in general (for example what a function call like `minPartition(S, n - 1, S1 + S[n], S2);` does) you could also try to understand it with pen and paper. Assume that `S={1;2;3}` for a start and track what your program does on paper. Those recursive functions will result in a binary tree and in the end you chek every possible partition. However this function does not create any partitions, but just calculates the result of the problem (the difference between the sum of both partitions)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Provide your trace and a *specific* problem; "I don't understand" is not a specification; it's a request for holistic tutoring, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your "more general question" should be answered by your `printf` statements; they will trace the order of execution for you.

Comment: I put an answer below, but this question is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.  If you would delete it from here and move it there, I will move the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Prune I'm sorry about this and thank you very much.

Comment: @churill Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Evan Thank you Evan, I read the help center of `codereview.stackexchange.com` but I think i couldn't ask this question there. I think it's for improving the code I already know how it works. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `minPartition()` is called for the first time, it'll run through to eventually get to `inc` where it'll run the call of `minPartition()`, and in that iteration of the call, either go through the base case or case 1, and it'll keep doing that until the base case happens. When that happens, it'll return the call, and then `exc` will run its call of `minPartition()` and basically repeating processing that happened to `inc` and when it reaching the base case it'll return back to another previous iteration of `inc` and repeat until it's back to the first iteration of `inc`, then `exc` will run, once `exc` finishes, the `min()` function just finds the minimum difference out of the values in `inc` and `exc`.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thank you but what is the use of this base case ? I know it's necessary but I don't understand the logic of it.

Comment: This implementation is basically a divide and conquer thing, where it's dividing its input every iteration, and the base case is just telling the code to stop dividing cause you have an empty list and can't divide it so just stop, and return out of this iteration and go to another. I don't know if I worded it right, but does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, somehow it makes sense. dividing the problem into 2 subproblems that has their recursion solution `S1 & S2` then combine the solutions with the base condition.